# Vaadin Chart: How to use Global configuration

Tags: vaadin-charts

There is a [Global](https://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin/vaadin-charts/4.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Global.html) configuration object, however I am not able to see how it can be used.

This is needed, for example, to set the `timezoneOffset`.

Since it does not apply for any specific chart, I would expect a static setting/getter somewhere, but I couldn't find a reference which [uses](https://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin/vaadin-charts/4.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/class-use/Global.html) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something is missing and that class is not used at the moment. Can you create an issue in github.com/vaadin/charts/issues/new ?
Other global settings like Lang or Theme can be set as shown in [this example](https://github.com/vaadin/charts/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/charts/examples/themes/ChangingThemeAndLang.java#L42)

As a workaround you can execute javascript snippet shown in Global javadoc.
Check vaadin docs for executing javascript https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-javascript.html

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(
            "Highcharts.setOptions({"
            + "  global: {"
            + "    timezoneOffset:60"
            + "  }"
            + "});");
```

Remember that `timezoneOffset` is in minutes

Comment: This was fixed in Vaadin Charts 4.0.4
https://github.com/vaadin/charts/releases/tag/4.0.4